# Trying to save a table export with file dialog box

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

```
Private Sub Command42_Click()
    Dim f As Object
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim P As String
    Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        f.AllowMultiSelect = False
        f.InitialFileName = "H:\Chuck M\UCPP\"
        If f.Show Then
        For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
                strFile = Dir(varItem)
                strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
                P = strFolder & strFile
                DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "UCCP Export Specification", "MOM_Table Export", P
            Next
        End If
        Set f = Nothing
End Sub
```

I currently have this however I am getting an error "Method 'FileDialog' of object '_Application' failed.

I have done some google searching but couldn't find much that helped me.

i just want this box to allowed me to save my comma delimited table export to a location I want and allow us to name it so we don't get each daily export confused.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thats strange, it works fine for me. what happens if you start a new workbook create a test sub and try to call `dim f as object` then `set f = applicaton.filedialog(msofiledialogsaveas)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive that error if:

- you don't have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module,
- your VBA project does not have the reference to the Office Object Library, and
- you try to use the `msoFileDialogSaveAs` constant name.

To fix this, either...

**(a)** verify that your VBA project has a valid reference for...

> Microsoft Office nn.n Object Library

...where `nn.n` corresponds to the version of Office you have installed (e.g., it is `14.0` for Office 2010).

**(b)** Failing that, you can use

```
Dim f As Object
Const msoFileDialogSaveAs = 2
Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
```

TIP: **Always** use `Option Explicit` for every module you create. It will save you many a headache. To make it the default, choose `Tools > Options` in the VBA editor and select "Require Variable Declaration". That won't add `Option Explicit` to any existing modules, however; you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: Well that solved the problem but presented one more. Saying that the table or database is read-only "runtime error 3027"

Comment: DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "MOM_Export Table", P

Comment: As you can tell I took out the Export specification to see if that helped but still the same error.

Comment: @Chuck Try exiting Access completely, then re-open your database and try again.

Comment: Same result. I have checked a few things but can't see anywhere that I am opening anything as read only. I haven added a command to open the table to it once and same error message even though I could edit the table.

Comment: I just had to specify the type when saving it (ie .txt) and I wasn't I thought it would do that as it was a text transfer. My mistake. Thanks for the help :)